# Why I obtain this error message installing the Ruby bundler gem "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, redmine

I am not so into Linux and Ruby and I am having some problem trying to install **Redmine** on an **Ubuntu 16.04** system.

I am following this official guide:
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step

I am finding some problem when I perform this command:

```
sudo gem update
```

because during its execution I am obtaining many error messages like this:

```
Updating ffi
Fetching: ffi-1.9.14.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ffi:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161113-6502-1eskdz9.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

I am not into Ruby, what exactly is this "bundler gem" of Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you two articles. There you will find some more info about your problem.

- [Different bundles for different applications](http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2016/02/different-bundles-for-different.html)
- [Building native extensions for Ruby gems](http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2016/06/building-native-extensions-for-ruby-gems.html)

But I'll try to give you a previous view of you problem and answer your questions.

- A gem is a specific piece of code designed and developed to a certain task. It may be installed as part of a Ruby application and used inside it. In a certain sense you may say it is a library as a JAR file, although differently organized and used. Gems allow Ruby developers to share and reuse code easily.
- Bundler is an application that keeps your gems organized. It downloads and installs all all gems you need in your app, updates them when needed and much more. With bundler you may organize all your gems in a single repository, using them for all your apps, or create a private bundle for each application, and the first article teaches.
- Most of the times you get this kind of error it means you haven't installed all tools needed to build programs in your system. This means the programs (gcc, ld and other building tools) and headers. The native extensions are written in C and they depend on C header to be built.

I hope this helps you. But if you have any other doubts I'll be pleased in editing this asnwer and try to help.

Comment: Ok tnx, now I will read these articles...but...what exactly is a gem? Is it something like a JAR in Java? (a way to package "executable" application)?

Comment: I edited to add an answer to this question. Answers are more visible there than here in the comment and may be of help to other people in the future.

Comment: but how can I know what is th "mising" not installed tool that generate this problem? Or can I think to install Ruby from 0 and then redo this operation? Could be a solution?

Comment: All Linux distributions I know have a meta package allowing you to install all your development tools at once. Ubunty certainly have such package named `build-essential`. You may install it with **`sudo apt-get install build-essential`**. I suggest you to install it before anything else and see what happens. Reinstalling everything is too drastic.

Comment: I try to install the build-essential but it seems that there is nothing to install (it is all installed): 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

Comment: Then we must review your Ruby installation. Have you used  `rvm` or `rbenv` ?

Comment: No, what is rvm and rbenv? I don't know them. Now I have perfromed "sudo apt-get install ruby-dev" to install ruby and then performing "ruby --version" I obtain the following output "ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127995/discussion-between-ed-de-almeida-and-andreanobili).

Answer (score 1):

Install `ruby-dev`:

```
apt-get install ruby-dev
```